# Поиск текста в определённом классе

Tags: javascript

Есть класс

```
<div class="active"> текст </div
```

Как из него вытащить текст с помощью js и записать его в переменную url? 
Пытаюсь вот так, но не получается. Что я делаю не так?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function First () {
    var url = document.getElementsByClass('active');
    var ds = url;
    aaa.href = ds;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Для чего нужна эта строчка `var ds = url`?

Comment: @Arnial отлаживал предыдущую функцию, не обращайте внимания

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам пример кода, результат вывожу в консоль браузера.

```js
window.onload = function First() {
  var url = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
  for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++)
    console.log(url[i].innerText);
}
```

```html
<div class="active">Test text</div>
```